# Elixir install SDK on windows (IDEA)

Tags: intellij-idea, sdk, elixir, intellij-elixir

How to install Elixir SDK on IDEA 15.0.3 in Windows 10 ?

[[image: 1]]
"That selected directory is not valid home for Elixir SDK"

Comment: How did you install Elixir?  Via Chocolatey NuGet or via the Windows Installer?  It will make a difference.

Comment: from win istaller: elixir-websetup.exe

Comment: All the users who've opened issues for IntelliJ-Elixir on Windows use that installer, so it should work now.  Let me update my copy on Windows and see if I get the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a "Corrupted SDK" error when selecting the `Elixir` directory instead of the `Elixir/bin`.  Since it worked for my Elixir 1.1.1 install before I updated, there is likely a different different format to the `elixir --version` for 1.2 than 1.1.1.  This was the case for Elixir on OSX (using homebrew) and Linux.  I'm guessing the output is another format for Windows 1.2.  Please open a bug https://github.com/KronicDeth/intellij-elixir/issues/new and I'll figure out why Windows' format isn't matching.